# I am trying to use a for loop in javascript to create a a table that displays * and for each row the columns increase by 1 *

Tags: javascript, nested-loops

```
***let numRows = 5;
let numColumns = 10;
let strRowOutput = "";
for (let row = 1; row <= numRows; row++) {
    for (let column = 1; column <= numColumns; column++) {
        strRowOutput += "*";
    }
    console.log(strRowOutput);
    strRowOutput = "";
}
console.log();***
```

thats the code so far but it only displays the last row with 10*.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMmv8.png)

Comment: Try to increment `numColumns` with `row`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second for loop condition should be dependent to the variable in first for loop like `column <= row` OR if you want to restrict the column to a maximum value, you can use `column <= Math.min(row, numColumns)`

Im using the second approach here

**Working fiddle**

```js
let numRows = 5;
let numColumns = 10;
let strRowOutput = "";
for (let row = 1; row <= numRows; row++) {
  for (let column = 1; column <= Math.min(row, numColumns); column++) {
      strRowOutput += "*";
  }
  console.log(strRowOutput);
  strRowOutput = "";
}
console.log();
```